# Managing visual state in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am building an app that needs to have only one item in a list be "active". Active is a deeper concept that has nothing to due with the selected item in the list. So far I am able to load the table with the proper "active" state (the green dots). What I am unable to do is have the dots turn on and off when a new item is selected as "active".

I have started down the road of KVO but I wanted to know if there is a clean pattern for turning on and off the highlight state of items in table cells.

[image: Status lights]

Thanks in advance,
Joe

**Update:**
Got it working and wanted to show the proper UI. Thanks again!

[image: Status Lights]

Comment: you mean after selecting the cell that is in active(green) state, it will turn on and off

Comment: No, selecting the cell has nothing to do with the trail's active state. What I would like to do is have changes in my applicationModel drive the active state. The active state is shown with a grey dot, when an item is active, it should be green. Currently in my application, only one item should be active at a time.

Comment: How does the user select an item as "active"?

Comment: What I am unable to do is have the dots turn on and off when a new item is selected as "active". -> explain this

Comment: Active is based on a download status. As items data is download the active state of that item is updated in the model. What the list needs to do is unselect all the other items when a new item is set to active.

Comment: It's hard to answer without knowing what an "item" is, what your data structure looks like, and how you do the downloads. Are they downloaded one at a time? In groups?

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I wound up having my model update every item in the list. That way each item calls observeValueForKeyPath. Then in that function I set the visual status to match the model value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've understood, your task is to implement your own "Active" state to table cells.

You can subclass *UITableViewCell*, and make a method that lets you easily change cells' states (like *[(MyCustomTableViewCell*)cell setActiveState:(BOOL)state]*).

In your customized *UITableView* (or it's controller), you can make a method, that let's you set one of cells as currently active (in implementation of this method you can easily set all other cells' states as inactive). Also you can do whatever you want with your app in this method.

**Edit:**
I've re-read your post. If you want to change cells' states dynamically (according to downloading status, for example), then, you can force your *downloadManager* (or something like that; I don't know, what exactly can change app model in your app) to send some specific message to your *tableViewController*.

Comment: I was trying to use the highlighted state of the image to represent "active". I think there may have been some overlap with the table cells selected state. I renamed my field to "running" and am explicitly setting the dot to grey or green. When I make the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath I set the image color based on the running state. Then I add an observer for that piece of data on running. Everything is working great now. Thanks to all for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. In `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, before returning the cell, **always** set the image to be the green dot or `nil` based on whatever determines whether an object (row) is active.
2. Whenever you update your data model with a new value for whichever object is active, **always** call `-reloadData` on the table view. Additionally, before you call `-reloadData`, check to see if a row is selected for the table view. If it is, first, save the index path of the selected row, then reload the table's data, and finally reselect the row at the index path you captured first (without animation).

Let me know if any of this isn't clear and I can provide some code to help with the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

initialize an integer variable globally like

```
"int selectedRow";
```

in viewDidLoad initialize it like

```
selectedRow=-1;
```

in your cellforRowAtIndexPath write the following condition
//Code in cellForRowAtIndexpath

```
if(indexpath.row==selectedRow){
[cell.dotImage=[uiimage imageNamed:"activeState.png"]];
}else{
[cell.dotImage=[uiimage imageNamed:"inActiveState.png"]];
}
```

In DidSelectRowAtIndexPath
//Code in didSelectRowAtIndexpath

```
selectedRow=indexpath.Row;
[tableview reloadData];
```

This can work like charm